# Restore Perfmon Action/View Menus after hiding?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring, perfmon

In Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition, Service Pack 2:

1. Start > Run... > perfmon
2. Select menu View > Customize...
3. Uncheck option "Standard menus (Action and View)"
4. Select button "OK"

How might I now restore menus Action and View to their default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the icon to the left of menu item "File", then select menu option "Customize View..."

Via this alternative method, you may configure screen "Customize View" to display menus Action and View.